# Calculate transaction fee from getrawtransaction

Tags: bitcoind

Is there an easier way than substracting vout to previous vin's transaction vout to calculate the fee paid for a transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. That is how the transaction is set and calculated in the first place.